Replace data in nested JSON object with SQL
I have a table dashboards that has columns id (uuid) and data (json, list of datagroups)
Here is an example of what could be found in the data column
[
  {
    "datapoints": [
      {
        "display_type": "alarm_indicator",
        "field_name": "F1",
        "id": "df839a89-1441-46f7-a54f-6ea063f7eb4c"
      }
    ],
    "name": "data group 2",
    "id": "36d2c219-9f27-4ae3-8529-8cb4242795c5"
  }
]

I want to be able to, given the input parameters dashboard_id, datagroup_id, datapoint_id, data to replace the datapoint object with the given ID with the value of the data param.
I had this query, which does the same thing but to the datagroup, not the datapoints in the group
UPDATE dashboards
SET data = JSON_SET(
    data,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        JSON_UNQUOTE(
            JSON_SEARCH(data, 'one', :datagroup_id, NULL, '$[*].id')
        ),
        '.id',
        1
    ),
    JSON_OBJECT(
        'datapoints', JSON_EXTRACT(:data, '$.datapoints'),
        'name', JSON_EXTRACT(:data, '$.name'),
        'id', JSON_EXTRACT(:data, '$.id')
    )
)
WHERE id = :dashboard_id;

But I'm having trouble adapting it to work 1 layer deeper.

this may be helpful, it shows how to search an array by a property value.

normalize your tables and data and updates wil be no bother anymore

Out of curiosity, why did you choose to store data in JSON when it's so difficult to update it?

Also please query SELECT VERSION(); and show what the result is. MySQL and MariaDB have different implementations of JSON features, and the solution for one is not necessarily the same for the other. MySQL and MariaDB are different products, and are not always compatible.
